# Creating an array form where each element is a 'select' type

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze, meteor-autoform

I'm using autoform on my meteor project and am using an `afArrayField` for my `dimensions` field in my `NewStack` form.

It currently looks like this.

[image: autoform image rendering]

And here's how it's being rendered:

**NewStack.html**

```html
<template name="NewStack">
    <div class="new-stack-container">
        {{#autoForm collection=stacks id="insertStackForm" type="method" meteormethod="createStack" class="new-stack-form"}}
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Add a Stack!</legend>
            {{> afQuickField name='desc'}} 
            {{> afArrayField name='dimensions'}}
        </fieldset>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Insert</button>
        {{/autoForm}}
    </div>
</template>
```

What I would like to see for each of the dimensions fields is a dropdown populated with the options I set in the schema (i.e. `dim1`, `dim2`, and `dim3`). However I can't seem to get the form to render as anything other than a plain text input.

**Stacks.js**

```js
StackSchema = new SimpleSchema({
    desc: {
        type: String,
        label: "Description"
    },
    dimensions: {
        type: [String],
        autoform: {
            type: "select",
            afFieldInput: {
                options: [
                    {label: "dim1", value: 1},
                    {label: "dim2", value: 2},
                    {label: "dim3", value: 3}
                ]
            },

        }
    }
});
```

Interestingly, if I change the `afArrayField` to `afQuickField` in **NewStack.html** It appears that autoform can now see my options (but I lose the array functionality obviously)

[image: select example]

Any thoughts? Is there something inherent about `afArrayField` that precludes me from using some kind of selection mode?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can specify options for each element in an array using `$`:

```js
const StackSchema = new SimpleSchema({
  desc: {
    type: String,
    label: "Description"
  },
  dimensions: {
    type: [String],
  },
  "dimensions.$": { // note this entry
    type: String,
    autoform: {
      afFieldInput: {
        options: [
          {label: "dim1", value: 1},
          {label: "dim2", value: 2},
          {label: "dim3", value: 3}
        ]
      },
    }
  }
});
```

[image: rendered form]

It is mentioned in the autoform [docs](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-autoform#afarrayfield).

Comment: Perfect. Thanks so much! I had looked through the docs, but didn't quite get that part. I'm really new at JS (only previous experience had been toy visualizations in D3) and am unfamiliar with the $ syntax. I have to wait 19hrs to award the bounty... but it's yours.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing your schema to:

```
dimensions: {
    type: [String],
    autoform: {
        type: "select",
        options: [
            {label: "dim1", value: 1},
            {label: "dim2", value: 2},
            {label: "dim3", value: 3}
        ],
    }
```

Comment: Doesn't appear to change anything.